# Creating doctrine's entities on runtime

Tags: symfony, doctrine, runtime, entity

Situation: My boss ask me if I can create an entity from a json file. Not populating one entity with values from the json, but creating a new entity with its corresponding file, table and relations.

Could anybody give me some documentation, or an example or an starting point?

Edit1: 
    My bad, [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad). I have been developing web apps with symfony (with doctrine as ORM) for about 2 years now. I'm used to its workflow. But i have never considerated this request.

Comment: I think we might need some more info.  Have you ever done any software programming?  Are you familiar at all with php?  Do you know anything about symfony or doctrine?  How about json?  Just a bit more context would help a great deal.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/1V1wkjRz0U8

Comment: I think @Kadriles has linked info exactly you are asking for! Cheers!

Comment: Yep. Many thanks @Kadriles.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot.

This is totally against the principles of how doctrine works internally. (Caches, Proxies etc)

What is even the use case?